# error when I dont write correctly at first the topic name

Tags: python

I have a function to send a notification, and Im always getting an error in this sendNotification function when I dont write the topic name correctly at first.

The topic name should have just one word and in this case it shows the message "Valid Topic Name".

If the topic name is empty or have more than one word it shows a message "Topic must have just one word", and I have again the validTopic() to ask again user to write the topic name until he writes correctly.

And this is working fine, Im just always getting an issue only when I dont write correctly at first the topic name.

I think its because when I dont write correctly at first the topic name in my sendNotification function is receiving an invalid topic name.

But I dont understand why, because when the topic name is invalid I have again the validTopic() function...

```
def sendNotification(topicname):
# here I have the error when I dont write the topic name correctly at first
createTopic = create_topic(topicname) 

def validTopic():
    topic = raw_input("Topic:")
    words_topic = topic.split()
    number_words_topic = len(words_topic)
    if number_words_topic == 1:
        print "Valid Topic Name"
    else:
        print "Topic must have just one word"   
        validTopic()
    return topic

def create():
    topic = validTopic()
    sendNotification(topic)

create()
```

Comment: Missing a `return`before the inner call to `validTopic` ? Anyway, in Python, it is usually *not* a good idea to use recursion instead of looping (using a `while` loop for example).

Comment: I see a `validTopic()` and a `validTopicName()` function. Is this a typo? If `validTopic()` is another function, what does it do?

Comment: Thanks for answer. It was a typo. Its the same function, I updated correctly that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If topic is invalid you're calling `validTopic()` again. But you're not using the result of this `validTopic()` call. You should assign the result of `validTopic()` to `topic`:

```
...
print "Topic must have just one word"   
topic = validTopic()
...
```

But I strongly recommend what Sylvain Leroux said: convert the recursion to a while loop.

Something like:

```
def validTopic():
    number_words_topic = 0
    while number_words_topic != 1:
        topic = raw_input("Topic:")
        words_topic = topic.split()
        number_words_topic = len(words_topic)
        if number_words_topic != 1:
            print "Topic must have just one word"

    print "Valid Topic Name"        
    return topic
```